# How do I do an inverse FFT transform in the code below?

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, ifft

Below is the code of the process of receiving the microphone sound in real time and performing the FFT.
For noise cancellation, it is blocked in IFFT process.
Do you have any resources or methods to help me?

Also, is there a library that performs inverse FFT inside python?

```
#complile by python3 new.py

import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import wave
import time
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 512
WIDTH = 2

#use a blackman window
window = np.blackman(CHUNK)

#load audio stream
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

player = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                channels=1,
                rate=RATE,
                output=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                channels=1,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

#do this for 10 seconds
for i in range(int(20*RATE/CHUNK)):

    sound = stream.read(CHUNK)

    player.write(np.fromstring(sound,dtype=np.int16),CHUNK)

    #unpack the data and times by hamming window
    indata = np.array(wave.struct.unpack("%dh"%(len(sound)/WIDTH),\
                                         sound))*window

    #take the fft and square each value
    fftData = abs(np.fft.rfft(indata))*2

    #find the maxium
    which = fftData[1:].argmax() + 1

    #use quadratic interpolation around the max
    if which != len(fftData)-1:
        y0, y1, y2 = np.log(fftData[which-1:which+2:])
        x1 = (y2 - y0) * .5 / (2 * y1 - y2 - y0)

        #find the frequency and output it
        thefreq = (which + x1) * RATE / CHUNK
        print("The freq is %f Hz." % (thefreq))

    else:
        thefreq = which * RATE / CHUNK
        print("The freq is %f Hz." % (thefreq))

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

Comment: [numpy.fft.ifft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.fft.ifft.html)

Comment: Using the above link iff will play a cracked sound instead of a phase inversion.
I do not know what to refer to here.

Comment: You used `np.fft.rfft` to compute the forward transform, you need to use `np.fft.irfft` to compute the inverse transform. But the code above takes the absolute value of the transform, you cannot inverse transform that.